# JSF2 + CDI @Produces keeping old session state

Tags: session, jsf-2, cdi, logout

I have an AuthenticatorBean declared as follows:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class AutenticadorBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private AutenticadorService autenticadorService;
```

This bean calls a method inside AutenticadorService that verifies user
credentials and @Produces this user in the Session like follows:

```
@SessionScoped
public class AutenticadorServiceImpl implements AutenticadorService, Serializable {

    @EJB
    private AnalistaRepository analistaRepository;

    private Analista analistaSessao;

    @Override
    public void inserirSessaoDadosLogin(String login) {
          analistaSessao = analistaRepository.buscaPorUserName(login);
    }

    @Produces
    @Named("analistaSessao")
    public Analista getAnalistaSessao() {
          return analistaSessao;
    }
}
```

The first time i log into the application it produces the user in session, but
the problem is that after i logout, and login again with a different user, and
try to

```
@Inject 
Analista analistaSessao
```

inside other Service the attribute is loaded with
the first user before i logged out. But if i access analistaSessao directly in AutenticadorService.getAnalistaSessao(); it returns the right user wich is the second one
i logged in.

Here's my logout code:

```
public String logout() throws IOException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    ExternalContext ex = facesContext.getExternalContext();  
    ex.invalidateSession();
    return "/home?faces-redirect=true&logout=true";
}
```

Does anyone knows the reason of this behaviour??

Thanks.

Comment: Never seen this before. I never use EJB, can you try with a pojo?

Comment: It's a good practice to translate your source code before posting. "analistaSesdadoa" will look like gibberish to most people here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you've done should work because you invalidate the session.

try to remove @Produces and @Named on getAnalistaSessao() from your AutenticadorServiceImpl and add this @Model class to your code.

```
@Model
public class AnalistaProducer {

    @Inject
    private AutenticadorService autenticadorService;

    @Produces
    @Named
    public Analista getAnalistaSessao() {
          return autenticadorService.getAnalistaSessao();
    }
}
```

Comment: you're welcome.. please note that Model Annotation is a Stereotype which use RequestScope and Named at the same time